# Importing @Before package options in Hooks java class

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumberjs, cucumber-junit

Am new to using cucumber tool. Currently learning concepts of Hooks and Tags. While importing @Before and the suggested option was 'import io.cucumber.java.Before;'. I see that in various tutorials the mentioned import is 'import cucumber.api.java.Before;'.

I ran my code with the suggested import but found that the @Before Hook code wasn't executed. I checked it using println statement.
Does both have the same functionality and why am not allowed to import  'import cucumber.api.java.Before;' ?

Cucumber related Dependencies in POM.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
         <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
         <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
         <version>2.12.2</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The combination of dependencies in your POM suggest that you are working on an existing project (and it needs cleaning up). When learning a new tool or reproducing a problem it is usually best to start from scratch.

Try following the tutorial and then add the hooks so you are adding them to a working project.

https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for the response. Basically i'm learning from scratch and added the dependencies as mentioned in tutorials. Every time i come across adding ''import cucumber.api.java.*****" am suggested only to add 'import io.cucumber.java.***;'. Why am i allowed only to add  'import io.cucumber.java.***;'.   Note : **** denotes other import options like 'CucumberOptions', 'Before'.

Comment: Check the dates on the tutorials. They are probably old. All the imports moved to match the package/module they're part of. So everything starts with `io.cucumber` now. Start with the tutorial I linked. You don't have to add any dependencies to use before hooks.